# CancellableFormController in Spring

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp

I'm trying to create a form which can be cancelled. I found that the class CancellableFormController exist. But couldn't find a good explanation how to use it. Its my understanding that you have to give a variable with the request. But how do you do this inside a spring form? If someone could help me implement this. Or just point me towards a good tutorial, as I was unable to find one.

Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: What do you want to do?  Do you just want to validate input and to reject the request on validation failure?  Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of the `SimpleFormController` API which is deprecated as of spring 3 so I would not encourage using it.  A substitute class in annotated MVC does not really exist but can be provided using multiple request mappings (modded example from [spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?113551-CancellableFormController-equivalent-with-spring-3-annotation)):

```
@RequestMapping(params="cancel=true")
public String doCancel() {
    return "cancelView";
}


@RequestMapping(params="cancel!=true")
public String formSubmit(@ModelAttribute MyModelObject obj) {
    processForm(obj);
    return "successView";
}
```

Comment: Ok I haven't looked into requestmapping yet because I'm fairly new to spring. I will do that now. But in my jsp page I just do this then:    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">

Comment: I think I understand a bit off requestmapping. It is as for example i would have the link "aPage.htm?cancel=true" params will check that parameter? And it will execute a method depending on the param? If so how do I implement that in a form. What will happen if the cancel button is clicked? How do I add the parameter with it? Because now I have the doSubmitAction method wich handles the request when the submit button is pressed. How does he know when the cancel button is pressed. Do I have to set an attribute and replace the doSubmitAction method with requestmapping methods?

Comment: In the form, have a hidden attribute that is set to true via JavaScript onsumbit, or change the RequestMapping to check for the value that the cancel button is set to e.g. `params="cancel=Cancel"`

Answer (score 1):

Simpler is usually better.  The easiest way to "cancel" a form is to just not submit it.  Why not make the cancel "button" a link that takes the user away (directly) to wherever you want the user to go after cancellation?

If you prefer a button, just style the link to *look* like a button.

The only circumstance where this wouldn't work is if you need to take a specific action upon cancellation, but that's not usually the case.  If it were, that implies there's some state or context related to the form that is *external* to the form.  In such a case, you should be using something like Spring Web Flow and that has well-established conventions for dealing with state transitions (cancellation is just a special case).

But, most likely, a simple `<a href="...">Cancel</a>` is all you need.  No sense overcomplicating things!

Comment: Yes indeed thank you. I did it with a button and an onclick method that redirects. But it's nice to know I can cancel it and take action uppon cancelation.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but a link has a distinct advantage over a button with an onclick event because it's guaranteed to work even when JS isn't enabled.  "Graceful degradation."

Answer (score 0):

With the implementation of Simple Form Controller, there are ways to provide the Initial and the Successful View to the Clients. But what happens when the Form is cancelled by the User? Who will process the Cancel operation of the Form?

The above issues can be given immediate solution with the usage of Cancellable FormController. The good thing is that Cancellable FormController extends SimpleForm Controller so that all the functionalities are visible to this Controller also. Suppose say that the User clicks the cancel button, the Framework will check in the Request parameter for a key with name 'cancelParamKey'. If it is so, then it will call the onCancel() method. Consider the following definition,

```
public class MyCompleteFormController extends CancellableFormController{

    public ModelAndView onCancel(){
        return new ModelAndView("cancelView");
    }
}
```